# Solve a nonlinear system of equations in 3 variables

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

I need to solve this system of equations
$$\frac 1x+\frac{1}{y+z}=-\frac2{15}$$
$$\frac 1y+\frac{1}{x+z}=-\frac2{3}$$
$$\frac 1z+\frac{1}{x+y}=-\frac1{4}$$
I've tried to express $x$ in terms of $y$, then $y$ in terms of $z$. But this leads to nothing good. I think I should use some matrix method, but I'm not sure what exactly I have to do. Need help here.

Comment: these are not linear?

Comment: @DietrichBurde you mean i need to do this? $$x=\frac{15(y+z)}{2y+2z+15}
...$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a linear algebra problem ! So multiply the first by $x(y+z)$ to get 
$$x+y+z=-\frac{2}{15}x(x+z)$$ similar for all the rest. Let $a=x+y+z$.

Then you have the linear system

$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{2}{15}&\frac{2}{15}&0\\
\frac{2}{3}&0&\frac{2}{3}\\
0&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{4}
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}xy\\xz\\yz\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\-1\\-1\end{pmatrix}a$$

Solving this by row reduction we get

$$2xy=-5a$$
$$xz=-5a$$
$$yz=a$$
Subsituting and canceling we have

$$x=-5y$$
$$z=2y$$

from which we see by adding those equations that $$a:=x+y+z=-2y$$
And then we substitute again to have 
$$yz=-2y$$ and thus

$$z=-2.$$

Comment: Typo in your first equation: $x+y+z = -\frac{2}{15}x(y+z)$. Don't forget to justify $y \ne 0$, $z \ne 0$ for your "canceling" step!

Comment: @aschepler The original equations imply that the variables are non zero.

Comment: Yes, it's easy to justify. But a couple of words really help.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is given by
$$
(x,y,z)=(5,-1,-2)
$$
This follows by multiplying with the common denominator, which gives three polynomial equations in $x,y,z$, which can be easily solved using resultants. The first polynomial equation, for example, is $x(2y + 2z + 15) + 15(y + z)=0$. One of the resultant equations is, for example, $yz - x - y - z=0$, so that we can substitute $x=yz-y-z$.

Comment: Sounds interesting, +1 I would like to see some of the details of your resultant argument.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Actually, I think that your solution here (+1) is better than using resultants.

Answer (score 1):

setting $$x+y=a,x+z=b,y+z=c$$ then we have $$\frac{a+b+c}{2}-c=\frac{a+b-c}{2}=x$$ etc. Can you finish?
the solution is given by $$x=5,y=-1,z=-2$$

Comment: what exactly should I do? Write $\frac1x$ like$\frac2{a+b-c}.And \frac1{y+z}as\frac1c$. Or what?

Comment: express $y,z$ by $a,b,c$ like above

Comment: $$\frac{a+b+c}{2}-b=\frac{a-b+c}{2}=y$$$$\frac{a+b+c}{2}-a=\frac{-a+b+c}{2}=z$$

Comment: your first equation is wrong

Comment: oops. corrected it

Comment: and now Nikolai write the new system and solve it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66803/discussion-between---and-dr-sonnhard-graubner).